# How can i make a generic keyof type to become a union type of distinct keys

Tags: typescript

I don't have the right typescript vocabulary to describe what i am trying to achieve, so i will be using my code snippet to describe what i am aiming at. I have two interfaces `ActionPayloadTypes` and `Action`

```
interface ActionPayloadTypes {
    FETCH_LIST_REQUEST: any,
    FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS: string[],
    FETCH_LIST_FAILURE: string
}

interface Action <T extends keyof ActionPayloadTypes> {
  type: T
  payload: ActionPayloadTypes[T]
}
```

and I'm wanting to create a union type of Actions based on these 2 interfaces.

Basically i want

```
type Actions = Action<'FETCH_LIST_REQUEST'> | Action<'FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS'> | Action<'FETCH_LIST_FAILURE'>
```

without having to write the union types manually for each key. I tried using `<keyof ActionPayloadTypes>` it creates a union type in the `Action`. See below.

```
Action<'FETCH_LIST_REQUEST' | 'FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS' | 'FETCH_LIST_FAILURE'>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Actions = {
    [A in keyof ActionPayloadTypes]: Action<A>
}[keyof ActionPayloadTypes];
```

You have to map each key of the `ActionPayloadTypes` type into a "call" to the `Action` type. Then you index this partial result with the keys of  `ActionPayloadTypes` to get the desired union.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path. As you noted `Action<keyof ActionPayloadTypes>` gives you a type where the generic parameter is the union of keys.

In order to get a union with each type of `Action` I break it into two steps:

First I use a mapped type to get a map with values for each type of `Action`

```ts
    type ActionMap = { [K in keyof ActionPayloadTypes]: Action<K> }
    // {
    //     FETCH_LIST_REQUEST: Action<"FETCH_LIST_REQUEST">;
    //     FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS: Action<"FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS">;
    //     FETCH_LIST_FAILURE: Action<"FETCH_LIST_FAILURE">;
    // }
```

From here, I can create a union type based on the values in this map

```ts
    type ActionUnion = ActionMap[keyof ActionMap];
    // Action<"FETCH_LIST_REQUEST"> | Action<"FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS"> | 
    // Action<"FETCH_LIST_FAILURE">
```

Of course, you can combine these into a single type to be more succinct

```ts
    type ActionUnion = { 
        [K in keyof ActionPayloadTypes]: Action<K> 
    }[keyof ActionPayloadTypes];
    // Action<"FETCH_LIST_REQUEST"> | Action<"FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS"> | 
    // Action<"FETCH_LIST_FAILURE">
```